# Use lambda to compare elements of 2-D array with Arrays.sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

We have an `int[][] nums = new int[n][2]` (where `n` is predefined). We want to sort this based on the difference between the elements in the array as below:

Sort array based on the difference as `nums[i][0] - nums[i][1]`

Example: `{{1,2}, {3,20}, {40,5}, {3,2}}` 
Difference between the elements in array: `{-1, -17, 35, 1}` 
Required final sorted array based on above difference: `{{3,20}, {1,2}, {3,2}, {40,5}}`

Is there any way to achieve this method of sorting using `Array.sort(nums, (x,y) -> (lambda function))` ?

Comment: What is meaning about `difference > nums[i][0] - nums[i][1]`?

Comment: @dyy.alex Updated the question. Is it better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supply two methods to solve it, one is sorted by `Comparator` and another one is by `Lambda`(it is what you want!)

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class lambdaFor2DArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[][] matrix = {{1,2}, {3,20}, {40,5}, {3,2}};
        // Sort By Comparator
        /*
        Arrays.sort(matrix, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                return (o1[0] - o1[1]) - (o2[0] - o2[1]);
            }
        });
        */

        // Sort By Lambda
        Arrays.sort(matrix, (int[] o1, int[] o2)->{
            return (o1[0] - o1[1]) - (o2[0] - o2[1]);
        });

        // Print Result
        for (int[] arr : matrix) {
            for (int a : arr) {
                System.out.print(a + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] nums = new int[][]{{1,2}, {3,20}, {40,5}, {3,2}};
        
Arrays.sort(nums, Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o[0]-o[1]));

Arrays.asList(nums).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x[0]+" "+x[1]));
```

Output:

```
3 20
1 2
3 2
40 5
```